# Make VS Code open Chrome browser when running 'npm start' React script when inside a Linux WSL2 distro on Windows 11

Tags: linux, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, wsl-2, npm-scripts

I'm developing on a Windows 11 system in an Ubuntu WSL2 environment and I need VS Code to open Chrome instead of my system's default browser (MS Edge), when I run the 'npm start' React script.

I've tried using the `cross-env` package to help me set the BROWSER env variable in the React script command but it's not working with the following permutations:

```
"start": "cross-env BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start"
"start": "cross-env BROWSER='chrome' react-scripts start"
"start": "cross-env BROWSER='google chrome' react-scripts start"
"start": "cross-env BROWSER=google-chrome-stable react-scripts start"
"start": "cross-env BROWSER='google-chrome-stable' react-scripts start"
```

Web developer life should not be this hard

Comment: Was browsing the internet for this issue, and I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/6hxk1z/comment/djhek92/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3. Have you tried setting the BROWSER environment variable? Perhaps try `export BROWSER='chrome.exe'`

Comment: setting BROWSER variable in .env file worked for me before, but not anymore after some updates